# Execute PhantomJS on a Flask Web App on IIS

Tags: python, selenium, iis, flask, phantomjs

I developed a python web app in flask and I'm trying to deploy it correctly on IIS.
Before i launch the app to production server I'm testing it on a VM.

All the steps i did:

- Install IIS with CGI
- With IIS installed, I download the web platform installer
- I installed the WFastCGI for Python 3 (my version)
- I configured the Handler Mappings and the CGI Settings to deploy my app, and is all fine.

The Website is all working, except one part. One of the functions of the website require execute a webdriver, in this case PhantomJS, with selenium python module.

The PhantomJS executable is on the root folder of the website:

```
PhantomJSPath = 'phantomjs/bin/phantomjs.exe'
```

But when i try to use declare the variable to select the webdriver his just don't run on IIS (when i open that specific page of that function it gives me a 500 ERROR, all the other pages work perfectly). The stupid thing is, when i execute by Flask development mode on port 5000 it just works perfectly.

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(PhantomJSPath)
```

I tried a lot of stuff already like give all permissions to everyone on the web app folder and stuff like that. I think the problem is with IIS configuration or security settings.

I hope you can help me and all of the other people with the same issue ;) TY

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i solved it. just configured the Website settings on IIS and Application pool to the specific path of the website, give all the permissions to the IIS user (IIS_USRS) and it works. Ty anyway!.

If you know any other ways to fix this issue just post. I Will mark if it works too.